# how to output keys in a key value pair within nested arrays using constructor Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, nested, key-value

Within the array of 'items' I wanted to output within the 'info' array only the keys: `[ 'stringTwo', 'StringThree' ]`
  and also output the value `String Three`

```js
let items = [
  {
    string: 'string1',
    info:
    {
      stringTwo:'String Two',
      stringThree: 'String Three'
    },
    size:3445
  },
  {
    string: 'string2',
    info: 'ruby files'
  },
  {
    string: 'string3',
    info: ''
  },
  {
    string: 'string4 without info key',
  }
];
```

I tried with both of these codes:

```js
data.forEach((data) => {
  if(data.info.constructor === Object) {
    console.log(Object.keys(data.info));
  }
})

data.forEach((data) => {
  if(data.info.constructor === Object) {
    console.log((data.info.stringThree));
  }
})
```

the first one should output the Keys `[ 'stringTwo', 'StringThree' ]`
 and the second one should output `String Three`

I'm wondering why in a more larger scale array that has more key-value pairs both doesn't work and gives me an input of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined`?
if so are there other ways without using constructor?

Comment: Are you sure your larger scale array has a "info" key on each item ?

Comment: `a more larger scale array` Sounds like at least one of its elements doesn't have an `info` property...

Comment: It doesn't exactly have an 'info' key. In the larger scale it goes by another name, i just changed it for the purpose of this smaller example but I followed exactly how it was in the larger scale but it doesn't read the property constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your larger scale array probably don't have any `info` key. To prevent having an error, you should :

- **Change your items** array to put an `info` key, even empty

  or
- **Add a** `typeof data.info !== "undefined"` **condition to check** if the `info` key **is defined** on each item before trying to access it.

Here is a working example :

```js
let items = [
  {
    string: 'string1',
    info:
    {
      stringTwo:'String Two',
      stringThree: 'String Three'
    },
    size:3445
  },
  {
    string: 'string2',
    info: 'ruby files'
  },
  {
    string: 'string3',
    info: ''
  },
  {
    string: 'string4 without info key',
  }
];


items.forEach((data) => {
  if(typeof data.info !== "undefined" && data.info.constructor === Object) {
    console.log(data.info.stringThree);
  }
})
```

Comment: So I tried this and it doesn't output anything. In my larger scale of arrays instead of the key 'info' Its called 'license'. I checked and i think this is what makes the difference but there is only one array that has the license. which is the one that I'm trying to get the keys from and also one value

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried, with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: where could I provide it? should I edit the question?

Comment: @I.Yezh Yes that's the better way to add it :)

Comment: I changed it. I can see why it wasn't translating well with the other array though I still cant quite figure out how to work with constructors in this case

Comment: What do you mean by "I still cant quite figure out how to work with constructors in this case" ?

Comment: I'm quite new to working with constructors in general

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, don't forget to `plus` and to mark it as `answered` to help others find it

Comment: I will, for sure.

Comment: what I dont understand is where the info would go in place of the license. as in which was the info key and which one is the info property?

Comment: If you want to use license, you can do it like this : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQbpxa